# MATLAB - produce a swept non-cosine wave?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to produce a swept square or triangle wave. The [`chirp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/chirp.html) function produces a swept cosine wave; is there a way to do this with the square or sawtooth waves? My approach right now, at least for something like a square wave, is

```
V = A*chirp(t,f0,t1,f1, 'linear', -90); %#change the cosine wave to a sine wave
V(V<0) = -A;
V(V>0) = A;
```

I can do the same type of thing with a triangle wave, but it's a little more annoying.

Generally speaking, is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swept-frequency is the same as evaluating a function

```
function(2 * pi * integral(f(t) dt))
```

where `f(t)`, the time-varying frequency, is linear with time.

Just write the equation for a line in two-points form:

```
f(t) = f0 + (t - t0) * (f1 - f0) / (t1 - t0)
```

and integrate:

```
function(phase0 + 2*pi*f0*t + pi * (t - t0)**2 * (f1 - f0) / (t1 - t0))
```

The simplest form of this is when `t0 = f0 = phase0 = 0`, then you get:

```
function(k * t**2)
```

Comment: Not quite so simple: The corresponding time-domain function for a chirp is the sine of the phase in radians where the phase is the integral of the frequency http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Linear_chirp

Comment: @learnvst: Yes, I suppose that distinction creates a factor of 1/2 which I'd neglected.  The result will still be a quadratic relationship.

Comment: That might work actually. The `chirp` function doesn't necessarily do what I want; shifting the cosine wave to a sine wave as in my example results in an initial concave up curve rather than concave down.

Comment: @Dang: The concavity is affected by the change in frequency as well as the shape of the function, so it might be concave up, depending on `f0`, `f1`, `t1`.

Comment: Ah, okay. So stick to `chirp` and shift it by -90deg to get a sine output, then use this solution for the square and triangle waves then, right?

Comment: @Dang: This answer should work equally well for sine, cosine, square, triangle, sawtooth, and any waveform you can express parametrically.  I expect it to work the same as `chirp` (+phase shift) for sine and cosine.