# Creating a swept wave type of signal without using chirp in matlab / octave?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

How can I create a swept wave signal in octave / matlab without using the chirp function.  I would like to do this because I'm trying to create a swept signal from a specific audio signal generated by octave / matlab not just a simple sin wave.

I tried piecing some code together found here [MATLAB - produce a swept non-cosine wave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679810/matlab-produce-a-swept-non-cosine-wave)
but ran into problems with the signal not being a second in length when fs=8000

```
%test sweep / chirp
clc
clear all
freq=200
fs=8000;
t=linspace(0,2*pi(1:freq/fs),fs); %

for nn=1:freq
    data(nn)=sin(nn*t(nn));
end

wavwrite([data'] ,fs,32,strcat('/tmp/del.wav')); %export file
plot(data(1:200))
```

here's an image of the signal plot along with my question and problem:

1) notice the plot is not going to 8000 samples due to the fact I
   would get an error if I did that.

2) And its suppose to go from 1-200hz over 1 second.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a vector named `pi`, or is it an error?

Comment: @HebeleHododo pi is 3.14 matlab / octave has this built in and knows how to handle it.

Comment: But when you do `pi(1:freq/fs)` you are trying to index a vector or calling a function. MATLAB throws an error saying too many input arguments. I don't have Octave, so I can't try, but I think it should throw an error too. Can you make sure you have not defined it?

Comment: @HebeleHododo I just ran it again on my system and using an online octave/matlab program over the web in the browser, and the code ran with no errors here's the link to the matlab/octave online browser program http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php

Comment: `pi(1:freq/fs)` returns the value of pi on the online compiler. Maybe I should ask what your desired `t` is? Is it 0 to 2*pi divided in 8000 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the wanted with this script. Remember the "*" after "pi", when you are not trying to index an array named "pi".

```
%test sweep / chirp
clc
clear all
freq1=20;
freq2=200;
fs=44100;
lenS=5;
t=1/fs:1/fs:lenS; %
f=freq1:(freq2-freq1)/length(t):freq2-(freq2-freq1)/length(t); 

data=sin(2*pi*f.*t);

wavwrite([data'] ,fs,32,strcat('/tmp/del.wav')); %export file
plot(t,data)

wavplay(data,fs)
```

I wrote this in Matlab, not sure how it will work in octave...

Comment: thanks for the code but the freq don't work when the variable lenS is changed here's a spectrogram of showing that it's off.  http://tinypic.com/r/2l9tao7/8

Comment: Could it be your sampling frequency that causes problems? is the plot you made of a file saved by matlab? Please post the code that causes you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This code will stop and start at the given frequency in case someone needs it.

```
clc, clear all,clf
start_freq=200;
end_freq=1000;
fs_rate=44100;
len_of_sig=10; %len in seconds
t=linspace(0,2*pi*len_of_sig,fs_rate*len_of_sig);
f0= start_freq; %inital frequency
f1= (end_freq/2)+(start_freq/2);%ending frequency formula
f=f0:(f1-f0)/length(t):f1-(f1-f0)/length(t); 

data=.8*cos(f.*t);
data = data - mean(data); %fix dc offset %needed or amp could be off and cleans up spectrum of signal 
wavwrite([data'] ,fs_rate,32,strcat('/tmp/del.wav')); %export file
```